# How to use VuetifyJS Advanced slots example with Google Places API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, google-places-api, vuetify.js

How to use the VuetifyJS [Advanced slots](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#example-advanced) example with [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro)?

[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLRvEE?&editable=true&editors=101)

```
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="model"
  :items="items"
  :loading="isLoading"
  :search-input.sync="search"
  chips
  clearable
  hide-details
  hide-selected
  item-text="name"
  item-value="symbol"
  label="Search for a coin..."
  solo
>
  <template slot="no-data">
    <v-list-tile>
      <v-list-tile-title>
        Search for your favorite
        <strong>Cryptocurrency</strong>
      </v-list-tile-title>
    </v-list-tile>
  </template>
  <template
    slot="selection"
    slot-scope="{ item, selected }"
  >
    <v-chip
      :selected="selected"
      color="blue-grey"
      class="white--text"
    >
      <v-icon left>mdi-coin</v-icon>
      <span v-text="item.name"></span>
    </v-chip>
  </template>
  <template
    slot="item"
    slot-scope="{ item, tile }"
  >
    <v-list-tile-avatar
      color="indigo"
      class="headline font-weight-light white--text"
    >
      {{ item.name.charAt(0) }}
    </v-list-tile-avatar>
    <v-list-tile-content>
      <v-list-tile-title v-text="item.name"></v-list-tile-title>
      <v-list-tile-sub-title v-text="item.symbol"></v-list-tile-sub-title>
    </v-list-tile-content>
    <v-list-tile-action>
      <v-icon>mdi-coin</v-icon>
    </v-list-tile-action>
  </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

I added the Google Maps Geocoding API, Google Places API Web Service and Google Maps Javascript API in the Google Developer Console and received an API Key.

Comment: What do you want to display from Google Places API? Means just name of places or anything else as well?

Comment: Only Places (text based only)

Comment: Using AXIOS to get data and adding API Key directly will expose your API key, also the browsers will block that against CORS policy. You will need to add server side code which will act as a proxy server to get data from Google Places API.

Comment: Also I do not have any API key for Google Places API otherwise I would have updated the code in provided CodePen accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an instruction how to integrate [Vuetify Autocompletes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes) component with Google Places API:

1) add a reference to Google Places API

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&libraries=places&key=--KEY--"></script>
```

2) the following example shows how to populate `v-autocomplete` component  with places using `getPlacePredictions` method of [`AutocompleteService` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompleteService)

```
search(val) {
  if (!val) {
      return;
  }

  this.isLoading = true;

  const service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  service.getQueryPredictions({ input: val }, (predictions, status) => {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      return;
    }

    this.items = predictions.map(prediction => {
      return {
        id: prediction.id,
        name: prediction.description,
      };
    });

    this.isLoading = false;
  });
}
```

[image]

[**Demo** on CodePen](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/Bvwzza)

**Prerequisites**

> Since *Autocomplete is a feature of the Places library in the Maps
>   JavaScript API*, first ensure that the Places API is enabled in the
>   Google Cloud Platform Console. Follow [this instruction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#GetStarted) on how to
>   enable Places API

Comment: I enabled Places API and followed your steps. After typing a place I get this error: `[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "search": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined"` Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Comment: Tom, have you seen the demo from my answer? Anyway if you could post a new question with an example which reproduce the issue, i could take a look

Comment: I have seen your demo. I copied everything, so I think the problem is the way the places.js gets adder or loaded. Currently I put it below the head section in **index.html**. `<head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=places"></script>` I'm using webpack in my project. Maybe the issue is related to that? Not sure how to upload a reproduceable build.

Comment: @Tom, maybe you could consider to a create a demo on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io)?